# Redshift SQL вычисления в последовательных записях

Tags: sql, postgresql

Добрый день!

Есть таблица вида

```
user_id action_time session_num page_sign
```

action_time - время посещения страницы, session_num - номер сессии, page_sign - номер страницы (от 0 до 3). Таблица отсортирована по action_time.

Сессии, которые нас интересуют: 
(посещения страниц кроме 1) -> 1 -> (посещения страниц кроме 2) -> 2 -> (посещения страниц кроме 3) - > (посещение любых страниц)

Остальные сессии, нужно убрать из таблицы.

Была мысль сделать примерно так:

```
SELECT *,
    CASE 
        WHEN page_sign = 1 AND lag(seq_sign, 0) OVER (partition BY user_id ORDER BY happened_at) = 0 THEN 1
        WHEN page_sign = 2 AND lag(seq_sign, 0) OVER (partition BY user_id ORDER BY happened_at) = 1 THEN 2
        WHEN page_sign = 3 AND lag(seq_sign, 0) OVER (partition BY user_id ORDER BY happened_at) = 2 THEN 3
        ELSE lag(seq_sign, 0) OVER (partition BY user_id ORDER BY happened_at)
    END seq_sign
FROM mytable;
```

но если я правильно понимаю, так делать нельзя.

Буду благодарен, если подскажете еще какие-то варианты!

UPD:
Пример данных

```
user_id action_time                 session_num page_sign
2231    2017-03-01T05:38:50.983000  1   0 
2231    2017-03-01T05:39:03.335000  1   2 
2231    2017-03-01T05:39:17.450000  1   1 <--
2231    2017-03-01T05:50:10.401000  1   1
2231    2017-03-01T05:50:14.103000  1   0
2231    2017-03-01T05:52:10.593000  1   2 <--
2231    2017-03-01T05:55:23.445000  1   0
2231    2017-03-01T05:55:30.985000  1   2
2231    2017-03-01T06:00:05.340000  1   1
2231    2017-03-01T06:00:07.992000  1   0
2231    2017-03-01T06:00:40.307000  1   0
2231    2017-03-01T06:00:43.179000  1   3 <--
2231    2017-03-01T06:35:33.116000  1   1
2231    2017-03-01T06:35:39.845000  1   2
2231    2017-03-01T06:35:45.003000  1   2
2231    2017-03-01T06:37:14.637000  1   3
2231    2017-03-01T06:39:22.335000  1   1
2231    2017-03-01T06:46:01.271000  1   3

2231    2017-03-01T15:17:50.912000  2   1

2231    2017-03-01T15:18:01.036000  3   3
2231    2017-03-01T15:18:09.947000  3   2
2231    2017-03-01T15:38:26.668000  3   1
```

Здесь сессия 1 подходит под условия, так как в ней есть посещения страниц 1, 2 и 3 в заданном порядке, а сессии 2 и 3 не подходят.

В результате из этой выборки нужно убрать записи о неподходящих сессиях (2 и 3 в примере)

Comment: ничего не понятно. приведите образец входных данных и результат, который из этих данных должен получиться

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую предоставить.

Comment: вообще нужны записи о сессиях вида user_id - session_num - start_time - end_time, но суть проблемы не в этом. Главное отсортировать ненужные сессии

Comment: У redshift я так понял диалект похож на postgresql так что вот те оконные функции что вы пытались применить доступны ?

Comment: Да, оконные функции работают, но вроде мой пример некорректен, так как я пытаюсь получить значение этой же функции из предыдущей строки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно как нибудь так:

```
select user_id, session_num, session_start, session_end
  from (
    select x.*,
           case when page_sign=3 then sum(pg2) over(partition by user_id, session_num order by action_time) end pg3
      from (
        select m.*,
               case when page_sign=2 then count(case when page_sign=1 then 1 end) over(partition by user_id, session_num order by action_time) end  pg2,
               min(action_time) over(partition by user_id, session_num) as session_start,
               max(action_time) over(partition by user_id, session_num) as session_end
          from mytable m
      ) x
  ) y
 group by user_id, session_num, session_start, session_end
 having max(pg3)>0
```

Во внутреннем запросе выводим счетчик предыдущих первых страниц на всех вторых. на втором уровне выводим уже на 3х страницах счетчик тех, который был получен на вторых. И на внешнем уровне остается это все сгруппировать и проверить для группы наличие таких третьих для которых нашлись первые и вторые.

Тест на [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/217cf/2)

Comment: К сожалению, такой вариант не будет работать, если пользователь посетит, страницу 2 до первой страницы. Может быть, я не совсем корректные данные предоставил. Если в выборке для сессии 1 поставить 0 в первой строчке, то работать не будет, а нужно, чтобы такой вариант учитывался. Подправил данные в посте.

Comment: Нельзя случайно в min для страницы 2 указать что-то в виде ROWS BETWEEN <после минимума для первой страницы> AND CURRENT ROW?

Comment: @PREVED7000 Тогда откатил ответ на первый вариант, он то скорее всего рабочий во всех ситуациях. В rows between только в oracle можно на данные смотреть и то не всегда, в postgresql скорее всего нет

Comment: @PREVED7000 Но range/rows это само по себе интересно, сейчас подумаю ....

Comment: Спасибо большое за рабочее решение! Получается, что решить подобную задачу в общем виде (для большего количества страниц в цепочке) на SQL не получится без увеличения количества вложенных запросов? Кстати, вроде бы range/rows работают в Redshift.

Comment: @PREVED7000 Ну пока ничего в голову не приходит. вот сделал второй вариант, уровней вложенности столько же. Но уровни вложенности на одних и тех же данных обычно не особо страшно (по крайней мере в разы лучше, чем подзапросы заново обращающиеся к таблице)

Comment: Второй вариант не работает, если в данных убрать все двойки, кроме первой (идущей до первой единицы). Ссылка на sqlfiddle с 
такими данными http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/85543/2  Или, например, можно поставить тройку на первую позицию и сессия не учтётся.

Comment: @PREVED7000 А, это из за 0 страницы. поправил условие. но если вдруг там еще будут какие то другие страницы, не участвующие в расчете то надо будет это учесть, так что бы условие реагировало только не переходы 1-2, 2-3. Ну или просто ограничить выборку только записями с нужными страницами (что возможно будет даже лучше, если записей левых много), но правда это нарушит получение начала и окончания сессии ...

Comment: Второй вариант всё еще не удалось заставить работать. Самый простой пример: если 2 или 3 стоит в первой строчке. Тогда максимум становится равен 3 и перехода никогда не происходит. Пытаюсь придумать, как заменить max на свой case, чтобы макс. значение менялось только при переходе на 1 пункт.

Comment: @PREVED7000 А, точно, туплю ... Если бы в выборке были только эти 3 вида записей то можно было бы просто lag сверять, предварительно никакие max не беря ... Кстати, range в postrgesql нормально работать не собирается, дает ошибку "RANGE PRECEDING is only supported with UNBOUNDED", т.е. там фактически ничего кроме начала группы задать нельзя.

Comment: если сравнивать с lag, то не будут учитываться переходы, если перед первой 1-цей шла 2-ка или 3-ка.