# RedSHIFT SQL работа с датами

Tags: sql

Есть код, честно взятый отсюда: [Redshift SQL вычисления в последовательных записях](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/783162/redshift-sql-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%85)

И переделанный под требуемую задачу.

```
select user_id, session_start, session_end
  from (
    select x.*,
          case when page='rooms.lesson.rev.step.content' then sum(pg2) over(partition by user_id order by happened_at rows unbounded preceding) end as pg3
      from (
        select t.*,
              case when page='rooms.view.step.content' then count(case when page='rooms.homework-showcase' then 1 end) 
                   over(partition by user_id order by happened_at rows unbounded preceding) end as pg2,
                   min(happened_at) over(partition by user_id) as session_start,
                   max(happened_at) over(partition by user_id order by happened_at range between interval current row and happened_at + '1 hour' following) as session_end
          from (select user_id, page, happened_at from test.vimbox_pages order by happened_at) as t
      ) as x
  ) as y
 group by user_id, session_start, session_end
 having max(pg3)>0;
```

Задача в следующем. Необходимо выводить всё тоже самое что и в предыдущем посте, только сессии заранее не заданы, и по определению сессия это какие либо действия пользователя в течение часа. То есть хочется, чтобы этот код выполнялся таким образом, чтобы                    `max(happened_at) over(partition by user_id order by happened_at range between interval current row and happened_at + '1 hour' following) as session_end` корректно отрабатывала. Уже перепробывал всевозможные варианты отсюда https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_interval_literals.html и отсюда https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_range_condition.html

Буду благодарен если поможете.
Ещё раз, код отрабатывает с ошибкой, но при

```
max(happened_at) over(partition by user_id) as session_end
```

всё хорошо. Только получается, что вылезает за сессию, а она может быть длиной максимум 1 час. Махинации с RANGE, BETWEEN, INTERVAL не помогли. Первый раз работаю с этой бд и оконными функциями, поэтому буду благодарен, любой помощи!

Answer (score 0):

Или может быть что-то вроде этого:

```
  select user_id, session_start, session_end
  from (
    select inner_state.*,
          case when page='rooms.lesson.rev.step.content' then sum(pg2) over(partition by user_id order by happened_at rows unbounded preceding) end as pg3
      from (
        select t.*,
                case when page='rooms.view.step.content' then count(case when page='rooms.homework-showcase' then 1 end) 
                  over(partition by user_id order by happened_at rows unbounded preceding) end as pg2,
                min(happened_at) over(partition by user_id) as session_start,
                max(case 
                        when max(happened_at) as maxHap between min(happened_at) as s and s + '1 hour'
                        then maxHap 
                        end 
                        ignore nulls
                    ) over(partition by user_id) as session_end
          from (select user_id, page, happened_at from test.vimbox_pages order by happened_at) as t
      ) as inner_state
  ) as outer_state
 group by user_id, session_start, session_end
 having max(pg3)>0;
```

Но всё равно не работает.

Comment: Это не ответ, отредактируйте свой вопрос дополнив его этим кодом.